# control placement of text next to image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to edit a wordpress theme.  I created a child theme and need to change the header.  The current header has the following:

```
<hgroup>
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/" title="sustainablewestonma" rel="home">sustainablewestonma</a></h1>
    <h2 class="site-description"></h2>
</hgroup>
```

What I want to be able to do is independently control the placement of the span but margin-top or padding-top is being applied to both the image and the span. How can I control that?

```html
<hgroup>
    <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-45795044_561214090992995_7744636018275385344_n.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%" alt="sustainablewestonma">
    <span style="display:inline-block;margin-top:10px"> Educate Initiate collaborate</span>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: I don't see `padding-top` anywhere in your code is it being applied via external CSS? You can override CSS the same way you override templates in your child theme folder.

Comment: Do you see margin-top?  I also tried changing that to padding-top.  But anyway the answer is to use position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

Is the style supposed to go in the html tag? If so, try putting a `margin-top:0;` on the image alongside the `margin-top:10px;` on the `span`.